# How to place close icon on badge (span)?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am using Angular, TypeScript in WebStorm. I am trying to put a close icon on top of a `span`.

The first picture shows the result I obtained until now, in the second one I made it look as I would using Photoshop:

[image: as it look]

[image: as i would like]

I was thinking to use span but I hope there is a more intelligent way to do that?

Here is my actual css:
NOTE : the dark blue side is in class "badge" the light grey is "general"

```
.general {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: small;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    height: 1.8em;
    margin-right: .8em;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: small;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
    background-color:#405061;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    left: -1px;
    top: -4px;
    height: 1.8em;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is incomplete.

Comment: Use `position: relative` on the container and position the cross with `position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 4px`